# C++ WinForms application dead slow in a 64 bits build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiling, slowdown

I have a WinForms application that is running fine under 32 bits, and is terribly slow under 64 bits (both Debug or Release builds). The environmant is .NET Framework 4.0, Windows 10. Occurs with different versions of Visual Studio.

Terribly slow means 1 second for 32 bits, 10 minutes for 64.

I have the feeling that the slowness occurs during the filling of a DataGridView, But I can't be definite.

I have tried using the Profiler, but all the time is spent in [External Code], which is completely opaque.

Have you already met a similar problem ? How can I investigate ?

Comment: Without code, it is impossible to say anything.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis: the code is hundreds of source files.

Comment: Just remove the filling of the grid and see what happens. You can also temporarily hide the window but still fill it, to see if it's a painting issue.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I added comment about orders of magnitude. This is not an optimization problem.

Comment: Try breaking into the debugger periodically while the program is busy.  The stack trace might tell you something.

Comment: Turn off the feature that hides external code from your stack traces. That way you can see _where_ it is spending time.

Comment: @PaulSanders: interesting, I coud try that. Though I am not sure how to "break into".

Comment: @Botje: how can I ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019 , and I vaguely remember that you can right-click "external code" to override it as well

Comment: @YvesDaoust Just click on 'pause' in the MSVC toolbar while running under the debugger.

Comment: @PaulSanders: interestingly, I have been debugging under Visual Studio (at least 8 versions) for 30 years, and never used that feature ! :-)

Comment: @PaulSanders: this said, the runtime seems to be stuck in TextOut/GdiFlush functions while painting a Common Control. (Unfortunately, the stack doesn't tell all...)

Comment: I once had a bug where I was invalidating a control in response to a paint message.  That caused, in effect, an infinite loop and made everything run like toffee.  Could it be something like that?

Comment: @PaulSanders: that's unlikely, the 32 bits version is working fine. I begin to be convinced that some incompatible versions of the run-time and/o .NET framework are the guilty.

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood the issue, not related to a GridView but to a TrackBar, that was assigned a too large maximum value, corresponding to tons of tick marks.

The issue was difficult to track for three reasons:

- it occurred only with 64 bits builds,
- it occurred asynchronously with the GUI update,
- it required mixed-mode debugging as the code was alternating between managed and non-managed code.

I could only spot it by following the method of @Paul Sanders: pause the debugger randomly and check the call stack (after loading the relevant symbols). After various attempts, I saw references to TrackBar methods.